# Firebase Realtime Database: Can't send or retrieve data from Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with Realtime Database: I can't send or retrieve data to Firebase from an HTML Page.

HTML:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAQqSYXa-TRHGQwx_Cz9mpg2dreT38tq6k",
    authDomain: "miparada-e0e6c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://miparada-e0e6c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "miparada-e0e6c",
    storageBucket: "miparada-e0e6c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "331834990091",
    appId: "1:331834990091:web:a1a7925f63be5faf"
};
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    function writeData() {
        firebase.database().ref("User").set({
            name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
            age: document.getElementById("ageField").value
        });
    }

</script>

<h1>User Database</h1>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "name" id = "nameField">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "age" id = "ageField">
<button onclick = "writeData">SUBMIT</button>

</body>
```

I'm not getting any results.

Comment: You should remove apiKey and other credential from your post ! Just use `*` for security issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a partial import of the Firebase SDK, you need to import the real time database as well as stated [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) , and call the function properly (with parenthesis).

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- import the real time database SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAQqSYXa-TRHGQwx_Cz9mpg2dreT38tq6k",
            authDomain: "miparada-e0e6c.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://miparada-e0e6c.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "miparada-e0e6c",
            storageBucket: "miparada-e0e6c.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "331834990091",
            appId: "1:331834990091:web:a1a7925f63be5faf"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

        function writeData() {
            firebase.database().ref("User").set({
                name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
                age: document.getElementById("ageField").value
            });
        }

    </script>

    <h1>User Database</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="nameField">
    <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="ageField">
    <!-- call the function with parenthesis -->
    <button onclick="writeData()">SUBMIT</button>

</body>
```

Hope it helps ;)

Also: watch out for the security rules, right now anybody can read/write anything in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code right after the script block

```
<!-- import the real time database SDK -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

because you didn't connect the real time database to your program